# How to nest 4 Gpu with Raspberry Pi 4 Model B?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, gpu, cryptocurrency

currently i'm trying to nest 4 Gpus with my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B RAM 8GB. could anyone told me how to do it ? i would to use Raspberry Pi to Mining Crypto.

Comment: are you asking how to connect unknown hardware to a Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/mine-cryptocurrency-raspberry-pi) by Caroline Dunn on February 25, 2021 from Tom's Hardware Guide suggests that...

> "Raspberry Pi is not supported by Linux miner software due to its ARM
> Architecture. Supported Linux mining software is based on x86
> processors found in typical PCs."

While it may be possible to use Raspberry Pi hardware to join a mining pool for mining altcoins, the suggestions provided in the article are only theoretical and Dunn states clearly in a disclaimer that...

> "(t)he easier and faster method is to download and install the free
> software associated with the mining pool of your choice on your PC."

However, that said, do take a look at the full article by Dunn, as it does provide an excellent example, for compiling a Monero altcoin miner on a Raspberry Pi from source.